# Error when using Spanish characters in vps

Tags: python-3.x, vps

First of all thanks for your help.
I have a script in python which I want to run from a vps, the case is that the script contains the letter ñ and other Spanish characters and when I try to run it from the ssh it explodes with an error... I have noticed and I can't even write these characters to the console as it shows me something like ( arg : 1)

The encoding and language are these: es_ES.UTF-8

any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: Does the script write output to the terminal? It's possible whatever terminal you are using doesn't support the encoding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.